# Make nav menu hover ignore margin

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-5

How can I make that menu-hover-pages hover ignores the margin and extend from top to bottom of navbar ? **Run snipped on full width.**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
.menu-hover-pages:hover
{
  background-color: #333 !important;
}
.menu-item-type-post_type:hover
{
  background-color: #333 !important;
}
</style>

<nav id="header" class="ps-4 pe-2 pe-md-4 pe-lg-4 navbar navbar-expand-md bg_triumph_black text-uppercas text-whitenavbar-dark bg-dark fixed-tops">
                
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-white"><li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-260" class="menu-hover-pages menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home nav-item rounded-0 ms-2 me-2 menu-item-260"><a title="Start" href="" class="nav-link">Start</a></li>
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-35" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page nav-item rounded-0 ms-2 me-2 menu-item-35"><a title="Contacts" href="" class="nav-link">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>                   </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                
            </nav>
```